# How to publish word files from windows application C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

In my windows C# project, I have several word files in my Bin/Debug folder, when I publish my project I am not able to access the word files, it seems that these files are not published, and getting file not found exception.

Can any one please help me how to publish those files so that I can access it with my set up. According to requirement I can not store my files on Hard disk or server, it should be with the application.

Please help me

Comment: Also check the permission on that application folder. Because sometime if happened that the application didn't read the file due to permission constraints

Answer (score 3):

You can add such files as "resources". That way these word files will be compiled into the executable. Read up here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Hi, But I didn't find the way to store word files in  our Resources.. can you please guide me in that?

Comment: "You can add resources to a project by right-clicking the Properties node under your project in Solution Explorer, clicking Open, and then clicking the Add Resource button on the Resources page in Project Designer." What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the debug folder for storing. For instance, you will deliver a release version once. 
This requirement is really weird. However, use Visual Studio to create a msi file (Windows Installer) to attach these (Word) files. Then, you can store these files on a hard disk.

[How to: Get the Application Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229654%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)